# Find minimal set of cosets $C$, so that each $2$ vectors in $A_n$ are in one coset in $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $F_2^n$ be the set of all vectors of length $n$ with values of $0$ or $1$ and $A_n$ = $F_2^n \setminus(11\ldots1)$. Set $A_n$ contains all vectors except one with all $1$s. We can consider cosets of codimention $1$ that lies in $A_n$. For example solutions of equation $x_1+x_2=1$ is such a coset.

I am interested in this problem: find minimal set of cosets $C$, so that each $2$ vectors in $A_n$ are in one coset in $C$. I have found this solution:

$x_1=0, \ldots,x_n=0,\ x_i+x_j=1$ for all $1 \le i<j\le n$.

It contains $n+ {n\choose 2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ cosets. I need help finding better solution or proving that minimal set of cosets has size $\theta(n^2)$ so no linear solution is possible.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that without the restriction that the cosets lie in $A_n$, a linear solution is possible. For example, when $n$ is even, take $$\{x_1=0,\dots,x_n=0\} \cup \{x_1=1,\dots,x_n=1\} \cup \{x_1+\cdots+x_n=0,x_1+\cdots+x_n=1\}.$$