# Blocking set for cosets of codimension $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

In this [paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316577900012/1-s2.0-0097316577900012-main.pdf?_tid=b65d8dcc-0d21-11e4-97a3-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1405540097_01ac012f4ee33f7009ec3dd18ab63e3a) following theorem is proved:

If $V$ is vector space of dimension $n$ over a finite field $F$ of $q$ elements then any subset of $V$ which meets every hyperplane of $V$ contains at least $n(q-1)+1$ points.

Does anyone know results if we take cosets of codimention $2$ instaed of hyperplanes (coset of codimention $1$)? and $q=2$. So the question will be:

What is minimal set in vector space of dimension $n$ over finite field of $2$ elements, that meets every coset of codimention $2$?

I am going to use it for this problem [Find minimal set of cosets $C$, so that each $2$ vectors in $A_n$ are in one coset in $C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863592/find-minimal-set-of-cosets-c-so-that-each-2-vectors-in-a-n-are-in-one-cos). In fact these problems are equivalent.